# Generalizing a result for Newton cooling to the full $n$-dimensional heat equation

Tags: heat-conduction

For Newton’s law of cooling

$$ \dot{T} = - hA(T - T_\text{env}) + C^{-1} P $$

with the solution

$$ T = T_0 e^{-hAt} + e^{-hAt} \int_0^t ds \, e^{hAs} \left(hAT_\text{env} + C^{-1} P \right) $$

(temperature $T$, heat transfer coefficient $h$, surface area $A$, heat capacity $C$: heating power $P$)

one can ask the question about an optimal heating strategy: starting from a given initial temperature, a given target temperature should be reached in a given time with a *minimum* amount of energy; equivalently, one can ask about the *maximum* temperature that can be reached with a given amount of energy.

We define the average power plus fluctuations

$$ P(t) = \bar{P} + \pi(t) $$

$$ \int_0^{t_\text{end}} ds \, P = \bar{P} t_\text{end} $$

$$ \int_0^{t_\text{end}} ds \, \pi = 0. $$

Using that in the solution one finds one term to be maximized:

$$ \text{max} \int_0^{t_\text{end}} ds \, e^{hAs} \pi(s) $$

Due to $ e^{hAs} $, this is optimized by the strategy *heating as late as possible*, i.e., at a maximum possible heating power with

$$ t_\text{start} < t < t_\text{end}: \quad P(t) = P_\text{max} $$

$$ \bar{P} t_\text{end} = P_\text{max} (t_\text{end} - t_\text{start}) $$

With the replacement

$$ e^{hAt} \to e^{H(t)}; \quad H(t) = A \int_0^t ds \, h(s) $$

of all exponentials in the solution, the same strategy applies for time-dependent $ h(t) $.

**Questions:**

Can these questions also be generalized for the 3-dim. [heat equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation), for homogeneous or inhomogeneous media, e.g. for an average temperature in a certain volume? Is a similar result like *heating as late as possible* known? Conversely, for which phenomena does this result not hold?

My conjecture is that a proof is possible without explicitly solving the heat equation.

**Conjecture:**

Given the heat equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$ \dot{u} = \Delta u + f $$

with a heat source $f(x,t)$ that is non-vanishing for

$$ f(x,t) > 0 \iff x \in V \subset{R}^n \wedge t \in [0, t_\text{end}] $$

and constraint

$$ F_V = \int_0^{t_\text{end}} dt \, \int_V d^nx \, f(x,t) = \text{fixed} $$

show that

$$ U_V(t_\text{end}) = \int_V d^nx \, u(x,t_\text{end}) $$

is maximized by the strategy *heating as late as possible*.

Of course the conditions for $f$ cannot specify it uniquely but will restrict it to a class of functions

$$ f(x,t) = 0 \iff t < t_\text{start} < t_\text{end} $$

Comment: The units in your first equation don’t match. Did you mean to divide the convection term by the heat capacity as well?

Comment: That‘s due to several different conventions regarding these coefficients.

Comment: So please specify these details, as most practitioners will expect $h$ to have units of $\text{W}\,\text{m}^{-2}\,\text{K}^{-1}$. Since you're discussing dimensional changes.

Comment: Sorry, but units are totally irrelevant for this mathematical question.

Comment: detailed conjecture added